# Swagger error - Blocked:mixed-content - Spring Open Api 3.0

Tags: java, spring, swagger, mixed-content, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a Java 11 project with spring boot 2.4.0, which was running with swagger 2.0 and we decided to migrate to Open Api 3.0.

Before migration, swagger was working fine, but now there is always a CORS error in swagger ui.

If I go to the Network tab in chrome, the error is `(blocked:mixed-content)`.

There is some prints:

Error that appears on the UI:

[image: Swagger UI ERROR]

Error that appears on the network tab:

[image: Error on console]

This is the parent version:

[image: Parent spring]

And this is the OpenApi 3.0 Version:

[image: Open Api version]

There is a cors configuration on my project:

This is the preHandle method on the class that implements HandleInterceptor:

```java
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {

        configuraCorsDaResponse(response); //THE METHOD THAT SET UP THE CORS OF OPTIONS

        String header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        if (Objects.isNull(header) || header.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalStateException(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_NOT_FOUND);

        header = header.trim();
        String tipoToken = header.substring(0,6);
        String token = header.substring(7);

        if (!tipoToken.equals("Bearer"))
            throw new IllegalStateException(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_NOT_FOUND);

        String[] url = extrairUrl(request);
        String urlRecurso = extrairUrlRecurso(url);

        AccessTokenAutenticadoRequest tokenRequest = new AccessTokenAutenticadoRequest(token, tipoToken, urlRecurso, request.getMethod());

        accessTokenAutenticadoService.autenticarRequisicao(tokenRequest);

        return true;
    }

******

//THE METHOD OF OPTIONS
   private void configuraCorsDaResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "3600");
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "Authorization, X-requested-with, Content-Type");
    }
```

And I have other class that implements WebMVCConfigurer that overrides this method:

```java
 @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

UPDATE:

I've tried to put `*` on ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS but still the same error.

[image]

Here are other print of the chrome console:

[image]

And finally, there is a print of the `Errors` tab:

[image]

Comment: that blocked request was it "GET"? Also you have there access control allow headers which I'm pretty sure can block some things. Check more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: @Szprota21 Yes, this request is GET. I've tried to put "*" ritght now and still got same error. 
Note: I've updated the question with other print. Can you check it out?

Comment: it looks like your resource is hosted on http and you are trying to connect to https website. Also this website ```http://dev-apiatransparencia.apps.os-cni.sistemaindustria.com.br/api-transparencia/gestao/arquivos/entidade/2/modulo/1?ano=2022``` automatically redirects to https. Try to disable redirecting and connect to ```http://dev-apiatransparencia.apps.os-cni.sistemaindustria.com.br/api-transparencia/gestao/arquivos/entidade/2/modulo/1?ano=2022``` If it will work then you just need to fix your network

Comment: @Szprota21 Swagger look likes it is started in HTTPS. But I would ask you, swagger is part of my application and both starts inside same tomcat.  Following this line, there is no why they start in different Protocols. Is this possible? We've take a look and the application os not running with API Gateway, so there is no auto redirect to HTTPS...

Comment: It's not about application starting on http it's about redirecting. You need to check for your server configuration, I'm not much familiar with these kind of issues, anyway it's not a swagger problem but you have redirects somewhere

Comment: I'm getting the same issue... Did you find the resolution?

Comment: @Virendra nop, we decided to downgrade to Spring Fox. But I suppose that the problem was in the Ingress on OpenShift.